# Вычисление выражения в обратной польской записи

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки, структуры, калькулятор

Имеется код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct stack {
    char info;
    stack* next;
};
struct var {
    char name;
    double value;
};
void addToStack(char sym, stack *&begin);
void showStack(stack *begin);
int priority(char op);
void showElementsInBrackets(string &output, stack *&begin);
void executeFromStackElements(string &output, stack *&begin);
bool bracketsBalanced(string input);
void countRezult(string output, double &rez, string operators);
int main() {
    do {
        double rezult = 0;
        string operators = "+-*/%";
        stack *begin = new stack;
        begin = NULL;
        stack *t = new stack;
        string input, output = "";
        cout << "Enter the expression" << endl;
        cin >> input;
        if (bracketsBalanced(input)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                if (input[i] >= 'a' && input[i] <= 'z') {
                    output += input[i];
                }
                else if (input[i] == '(') {
                    addToStack(input[i], begin);

                }
                else if (operators.find(input[i]) != string::npos) {
                    if (begin == NULL) {
                        addToStack(input[i], begin);
                    }
                    else {
                        while (begin != NULL && priority(begin->info) >= priority(input[i])) {
                            output += begin->info;
                            t = begin;
                            begin = begin->next;
                            delete t;
                        }
                        addToStack(input[i], begin);
                    }
                }
                else if (input[i] == ')') {
                    showElementsInBrackets(output, begin);
                }
            }
            executeFromStackElements(output, begin);
            cout << "Output:" << endl;
            cout << output << endl;
            countRezult(output, rezult, operators);
        }
        cout << "Press Enter to continue" << endl;
    } while (_getch() == 13);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void addToStack(char sym, stack *& begin)
{
    stack *t = new stack;
    t->info = sym;
    t->next = begin;
    begin = t;
}

void showStack(stack * begin)
{
    stack *t = begin;
    while (t != NULL) {
        cout << t->info << endl;
        t = t->next;
    }
}

int priority(char op)
{
    if (op == '(') {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (op == '+' || op == '-') {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (op == '*' || op == '/' || op == '%') {
        return 3;
    }
    else if (op == '^') {
        return 4;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}

void showElementsInBrackets(string & output, stack *& begin)
{
    stack *t;
    while (begin->info != '(' && begin != NULL) {
        output += begin->info;
        t = begin;
        begin = begin->next;
        delete t;
    }
    t = begin;
    begin = begin->next;
    delete t;
}

void executeFromStackElements(string & output, stack *& begin)
{
    stack *t;
    while (begin != NULL) {
        output += begin->info;
        t = begin;
        begin = begin->next;
        delete t;
    }
}

bool bracketsBalanced(string input)
{
    stack *br = NULL;
    stack *t = new stack;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (input[i] == '(') {
            addToStack(input[i], br);
        }
        else if (input[i] == ')') {
            if (br == NULL) {
                cout << "Balance of brackets is broken" << endl;
                return false;
            }
            else {
                t = br;
                br = br->next;
                delete t;
            }
        }
    }
    if (br == NULL) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Balance of brackets is broken" << endl;
        return false;
    }
}

void countRezult(string output, double & rez, string operators)
{
    vector <var> vars;
    bool vectContains;
    var variable;
    for (int i = 0; i < output.length(); i++) {
        vectContains = false;
        if (output[i] >= 'a' && output[i] <= 'z') {
            for (int j = 0; j < vars.size(); j++) {
                if (output[i] == vars[j].name) {
                    vectContains = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!vectContains) {
                variable.name = output[i];
                variable.value = 0;
                vars.push_back(variable);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < vars.size(); i++) {
        cout << "Enter " << vars[i].name << endl;
        cin >> vars[i].value;
    }
    double a, b;
    for (int i = 0; i < output.length(); i++) {
        if (operators.find(output[i]) != string::npos) {
            for (int j = 0; j < vars.size(); j++) {
                if (output[i - 2] == vars[j].name) {
                    a = vars[j].value;
                }
                else if (output[i - 1] == vars[j].name) {
                    b = vars[j].value;
                }
            }
            if (output[i] == '+') {
                a += b;
            }
            else if (output[i] == '-') {
                a -= b;
            }
            else if (output[i] == '*') {
                a *= b;
            }
            else if (output[i] == '/') {
                a /= b;
            }
            output.erase(output.begin() + i-1);
            output.erase(output.begin() + i - 1);
        }
    }

}
```

Задача - перевести выражение в ОПЗ и вычислить его. С переводом проблем нету, а вот с вычислением трудности. Вычисления провожу в функции `void countRezult(string output, double & rez, string operators)` И руководствуюсь следующей логикой: все операторы, которые использую - бинарные, поэтому считываю 2 символа строки, которые идут перед оператором, произвожу вычисление и записываю значение в переменную, которая стоит за 2 символа до оператора, а символ, стоящий перед оператором и сам оператор удаляю. Однако все равно не понимаю, как потом из всех этих переменных получить результат

Comment: Если все сделано правильно и выражение корректное, то в спсике переменных должна остаться одна - это и будет ответ.

Answer (score 1):

В код не вчитывался, но основная проблема в вашем описании тут:

> а символ, стоящий перед оператором и сам оператор удаляю. Однако все равно не понимаю, как потом из всех этих переменных получить результат

Их нужно не удалять, а заменять на результат:

```
(1 2 +) 5 3 - *
3 (5 3 -) *
(3 2 *)
6
```

Comment: По идее, в посте написано то же, что вы говорите, только другими словами: *"записываю значение в переменную, которая стоит за 2 символа до оператора, а символ, стоящий перед оператором и сам оператор удаляю"* - т.е. два числа и оператор заменяются на одно число.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Тогда я присоединяюсь к вашему вопросу выше.